# ERROR: Failed to buil gem native extension because PostgreSQL is too old

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm attempting to run `bundle` in my Rails project on Mavericks. It fails when getting to the `pg` gem with this error.

It said **Your PostgreSQL is too old. Either install an older version of this gem or upgrade your database.**. so I installed `postgresql-9.3.4` and `gem install gem` but same error occurred.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /path/to/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/php5/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... no
Your PostgreSQL is too old. Either install an older version of this gem or upgrade your database.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/path/to/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding your postgresql installation to your path:

```
export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.3.4/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thank you! @Sergio A, I can install pg gem without any trouble.